# List manipulation and end-cases

Tags: scheme

I am attempting to learn scheme (for expansion of mind not homework), and am still wrestling with its differences compared to procedural languages.

Consider the following:

In procedural language terms I have two zero-based integer arrays a and b of lengths n>=1 and n+1 respectively and want to output an array c of length n+1 where:

c[0] = b[0] + a[0];
c[n] = b[n] + a[n-1];
c[i] = b[i] + Max(a[i-1],a[i]) (1 <= i <= n-1)

So, for example if a = [5,6,1] and b = [1,2,3,4], then c= [6,8,9,5]

I can do this simply in a procedural language. For example in Pascal:

```
function MaxAdd(a, b : array; n : integer) : array;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  c[0] = b[0] + a[0];
  c[n] = b[n] + a[n-1];
  for i = 1 to n-1 do
    c[i] = b[i] + Max(a[i-1],a[i]);
result := c;
end;
```

I am trying to do the same with scheme where I usetwo lists of integers instead of arrays. The following works, but seems clumsy to me. Is there a tidier way to handle end-cases?

```
 (define (max a b)
   (if (> a b) a b)) 

 (define (maxaddhelper l1 l2)
   (cond 
     ((= 1 (length l1)) (list (+ (car l1) (car l2))))
     (else (cons 
       (+ (max (car l1) (car (cdr l1))) (car l2)) 
       (maxaddhelper (cdr l1) (cdr l2))      ))))

 (define (maxadd l1 l2)
   (cond 
     ((= 1 (length l1)) (list (+ (car l1) (car l2)) (+ (car l1) (car (cdr l2)))))
     (else 
       (cons (+ (car l1) (car l2)) 
       (maxaddhelper l1 (cdr l2)) ))))
```

test output...

```
 Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.93 [3m].
 Language: scheme; memory limit: 128 MB.
 > (maxadd (list 5 6 1) (list 1 2 3 4))

 (6 8 9 5)
 >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem makes heavy use of indexes, so is better suited for a Scheme `vector` - which offers the same efficient index-based operations as an array. For example, an idiomatic solution in Racket would be:

```
(define (max-add a b)
  (let* ([n (vector-length a)]
         [c (make-vector (add1 n))])
    (vector-set! c 0 (+ (vector-ref b 0)
                        (vector-ref a 0)))
    (vector-set! c n (+ (vector-ref b n)
                        (vector-ref a (sub1 n))))
    (for ([i (in-range 1 n)])
      (vector-set! c i (+ (vector-ref b i)
                          (max (vector-ref a (sub1 i))
                               (vector-ref a i)))))
    c))

(max-add '#(5 6 1) '#(1 2 3 4))
=> '#(6 8 9 5)
```

Nobody said that *all* problems in Scheme must be solved using linked lists, this example in particular shows that sometimes you have to choose the data structure better suited for the job. If lists are a necessity, then `list->vector` and `vector->list` will allow you to switch back and forth between data structures.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by @uselpa, it's also possible to solve this problem using only lists, more in the spirit of SICP and idiomatic for Scheme. For completeness sake here's my implementation, a bit simpler and easier to understand than the other answer:

```
(define (max-add a b)
  (let loop ([a a] [b b] [prev (car a)])
    (if (null? a)
        (list (+ (car b) prev))
        (cons (+ (car b) (max prev (car a)))
              (loop (cdr a) (cdr b) (car a))))))

(max-add '(5 6 1) '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(6 8 9 5)
```

Comment: Thanks - can you recommend a tutorial that covers vectors and the 'for' looping structure you use - they don't appear to be covered in SICP (as far as I have read anyway)?

Comment: It depends on the interpreter, I encourage people to use Racket, it's great for learning, there exist modules for supporting SICP, and has nice extras, like [Iterations and Comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html). Here's the relevant chapter on [vectors](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html), they're no different from arrays in other languages

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's a list-based solution implemented in pure Scheme:

```
(define (maxadd lst1 lst2)
  (let loop ((last (car lst1)) (lst1 lst1) (lst2 lst2))
    (if (null? lst2)
        '()
        (let ((ca1 (car lst1)) (cd1 (cdr lst1)))
          (cons (+ (max last ca1) (car lst2))
                (loop ca1 (if (null? cd1) lst1 cd1) (cdr lst2)))))))
```

then

```
> (maxadd '(5 6 1) '(1 2 3 4))
'(6 8 9 5)
```